# Question about formula for negative binomial

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> An underground military installation is fortified to the extent that it can withstand up to three direct hits from air-to-surface missiles and still function.  Suppose an enemy aircraft is armed with missiles, each having a 30% chance of scoring a direct hit.
>   Find the probability that the enemy aircraft will have to fire at least five missiles to destroy the installation

So if this is negative binomial, x=5, r=3, and p=.3
So $P(X=5)= $ $7 \choose 2$$(.3^3)(.7^5)$$=.095$

Is that right? Because the formula for negative binomial in my book doesn't match up with sources online. My textbook says nb(x; r, p)= ${x+r-1} \choose {r-1}$$p^r(1-p)^x$

Comment: Doesn't that answer seem awfully low to you? The only way you could fail to require at least five is if the first four shots were all direct hits, a low probability event.

Comment: Do I just have the wrong variables? I'm just plugging them into the formula. Unless the answer is $1-P(X=4)-(X=3)$? In which case the answer would be .9163?

Comment: I have no idea what formula you are using.  Formulas are dangerous, think about the problem you are solving.  In this case, the complementary event is "the installation was destroyed in fewer than five shots".  Well, since it takes four hits that means that the first four shots were all hits, a probability $.3^4$ event.  Thus your answer is $1-.3^4=.9919$.

Comment: It takes 3 hits, not 4

Comment: Not according to you...you say "it can withstand up to $3$ hits".  Maybe that's a language issue...if I say "my car can hold up to $5$ people" that means it can hold $5$ people.

Comment: But let's say it only takes $3$ hits.  Now you need to also subtract the probability that exactly  three of the first four shots were hits.  Can you compute that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the term "negative binomial distribution" is used in a number of different senses:

- The distribution of the number of failures before the $r$th success,
- The distribution of the number of trials needed to get $r$ sucesses,
- Either of the above with the roles of "success" and "failure" interchanged.

But you can also do the problem by a different method: The probability that it takes at least five trials is the same as the probability of at least one failure in the first four trials.  That is complementary to the event of the first four trials all being successes, which happens with probability $0.3^4$.